# Matplotlib: Bar graph where values are shown for all classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

my main objective is to have a bar graph in a way that I can plot the values of all the classes one over the other, but I am still able to easily identify the specific value of each one of them. A sort of stacked graph in which the class that is below might change. For example, for the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = np.array([ [0., 2. , 0. , 4. ], [0., 4., 0., 2.] ])

colors = [(0.2588,0.4433,1.0),(1.0,0.5,0.62)]       

graph, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(len(data)):
    ax.bar(np.arange(data.shape[1]),data[i,:],0.35,color=colors[i],label=str(i))  


plt.show()
```

I would like to visualize the following graph (edited):
[image]

Notice that I can easily visualize that the blue class has values 2.0 for x-axis 1 and 4.0 for x-axis 3. I can also observe values for the pink class.

However, the code above generates the following graph:

[image]

and I lost the information about the value of the blue class on x-value = 1 because the pink class was plotted after it.

Any ideas on how I can change the codification to accomplish what I need?
Thanks.

Comment: I think this kind of plot would be rather confusion. I'd rather plot the bars next to each other.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The problem is that I will be using it to display histograms that will have a lot of bars spacially close one to another. If I display separated bars next to each other for each class it will be very hard to visualize the distributions.

Comment: If this is for a histogram, did you consider not using bars at all, but maybe just a step-like line?